# Ruby on Windows: Require is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: ruby, windows, cmd, guard, asciidoctor

I'm trying to use Guard to monitor changes in AsciiDoctor file. Here is *Guardfile* from official docs:

```
require 'asciidoctor'

guard 'shell' do
  watch(/^mydoc\.adoc$/) {|m|
    Asciidoctor.convert_file m[0]
  }
end
```

It works for me. But now, I'm trying to launch the same things without creating Guardfile - i.e. I want simply write these commands in Windows cmd.exe.

But when I write `require 'asciidoctor'` command prompt gives me an error:

> 'require' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Well, I know that such error messages are often have something with Windows `%Path%` environment variable. But I don't understand how to fix it in this particular case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby and DOS Batch are two completely different programming languages that have absolutely nothing to do with each other. You simply cannot expect an interpreter for DOS Batch to be able to run Ruby code and vice versa. (Especially considering that Ruby didn't even exist when `CMD.EXE` was written, so how could `CMD.EXE` possibly know how to interpret Ruby code?)

You need to run Ruby code in a Ruby interpreter (or use a Ruby compiler to compile it to something that you have an interpreter for).

Comment: Thank you. I see, my question have a lot of downvotes, so I should note that I already knew that I can't  simply run `require` in command prompt. The actual question is that I can't understand what is the correct way to run this `require`. What exactly steps?

Comment: This is Ruby code. You need to run it in a Ruby interpreter.

Comment: Actually, to be more precise: this is a DSL for a Ruby gem called `guard`. You need to run it with Guard, because the `Kernel#guard` method is provided by the Guard gem, it is not part of the Ruby core library.

Comment: **"You need to run it in a Ruby interpreter"** - well, I tried to launch `ruby.exe require  'asciidoctor'` in my Ruby directory, but it doesn't work. I assumed that ruby.exe is actually an interpreter, but probably it's not correct? **"Actually, to be more precise..."** - so, in simple words, I can't run Guard for AsciiDoctor without physically creating Guardfile?

Comment: Like almost all interpreters (including `CMD.EXE`), the Ruby interpreter takes its input from stdin, not as commandline arguments. I am not familiar enough with Guard to answer your question, you'll have to check the documentation.

Comment: **"Like almost all interpreters (including `CMD.EXE`), the Ruby interpreter takes its input from stdin, not as commandline arguments.** - Could you show the code, please? I mean, how to launch Ruby interpreter with `require` correctly parsed?

Comment: @johnc.j. You might want to have a look at [the documentation of guard](https://github.com/guard/guard/blob/master/README.md#usage)